# Could not translate host name "db" to address using Postgres, Docker Compose and Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

In one folder I have 3 files: base.py, Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

**base.py:**

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='base123' user='postgres' host='db' password='pw1234'")
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary

COPY base.py base.py

RUN python base.py
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pw1234
      POSTGRES_DB: base123
  aprrka:
    build: .    
    depends_on:
      - db
```

After I ran `docker-compose up`, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "base.py", line 5, in <module>
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='base123' user='postgres' host='db' password='pw1234'")
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known

ERROR: Service 'aprrka' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c python base.py' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I don't know why I have this error. I exposed port 5432. By default Compose sets up a single network for app. Each service joins the default network, I think that my app with postgres should work together. Did I write incorrect docker-compose.yml?

Comment: jack-gore's answer addresses your question. One approach for your diagnosis could have been to use a known good 2nd container to access the `db`. See the image's documentation on docs.docker.com and the use of the `adminer` image (https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#-via-docker-stack-deploy-or-docker-compose). Second, the Dockerfile would benefit from reducing the number of layers created by reducing the number of `RUN` commands. For example `RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python-pip` (you don't need the final `apt-get update`).

Comment: I had the same issue, and what helped was: 1) stopping docker containers in the docker Desktop interface; 2) closing the terminal where the python script runs; 3) opening the new terminal window where the script was re-run.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The problem is you should not be running `python base.py` as part of the `RUN` directive.

The `RUN` directive is executed only when you are building the image. The `postgres` container is not running at this point, nor has the network been created. Instead you want to use the `CMD` directive.

Change the `Dockerfile` to this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install psycopg2-binary

COPY base.py base.py

CMD ["python", "base.py"]
```

The above should result in the hostname `db` to be resolved. However if your python code doesn't have any reconnection logic for connecting to the database the container will likely still error out. This because the `postgres` container will be running but the database won't be ready to accept connections.

This can be temporarily fixed by adding `restart: always` to your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    expose:
      - "5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pw1234
      POSTGRES_DB: base123
  aprrka:
    restart: always
    build: .    
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Hopefully this will get you up and running.

Comment: Thank You! It is sad but I still don't know how to fix next error. aprrka_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "base.py", line 5, in <module>
   conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='base123' user='postgres' host='db' password='pw1234'")
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "db" (172.20.0.2) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: This error is what the second part of my answer tried to fix. You either need to add reconnection logic to your code, add the `restart: always` to your compose-file. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I did. It works, but firsts of tryies to connect to db are unsuccessful. Do I need to type in my base.py file some 'wait time' to make connection correctly without errors? I suppose that it won't be 'better' for my whole Docker image, but it will be nicer to see how it runs. Is my sollution correct?

Comment: Yes, this is a seperate question, but you want to implement some sort of waiting mechanism in your code.

Answer (score 26):

Add database and web service on **same network** in docker compose file. Also **link** db service and start web service after starting db service.

After properly adding **network, link and depends_on** configuration in docker compose file issue will be fixed.

Configuration example:

```
  services:
      db:
          container_name: db
          networks:
              - djangonetwork
      web:
          depends_on:
             - db
          links:
             - db:db
          networks:
             - djangonetwork

  networks:
      djangonetwork:
          driver: bridge
```

In my docker compose file, I have used network name as 'djangonetwork', you can use any other name.

the above configuration helped me to resolve the issue 'Could not translate host name db'.

Comment: This worked for me. Keep on forgetting to add a network whenever I create a new service.

Comment: Setting a `links` entry of `db:db` seems to be superfluous, judging [from the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#link-containers). What's your intention behind it?

Comment: You don't have to set the network explicitly. By default, a network is already created for multi container applications and each container join the network with its container name. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 12):

If you're using docker-compose first add this line to your .yml:

```
environment:
  - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

After that you start only you db docker:

```
docker-compose up db
```

It should start normally with a message like:

```
Recreating db... done
Attaching to db
db_1           | ********************************************************************************
db_1           | WARNING: POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD has been set to "trust". This will allow
db_1           |          anyone with access to the Postgres port to access your database without
db_1           |          a password, even if POSTGRES_PASSWORD is set. See PostgreSQL
db_1           |          documentation about "trust":
db_1           |          https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
db_1           |          In Docker's default configuration, this is effectively any other
db_1           |          container on the same system.
db_1           | 
db_1           |          It is not recommended to use POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust. Replace
db_1           |          it with "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" instead to set a password in
db_1           |          "docker run".
db_1           | ********************************************************************************
```

ADVISE: This is NOT SAFE to do.
If You decide to use this solution, make sure to list your docker file in .gitignore so you won't push this to production.

Comment: I posted this in another answer, but this is not a good idea. Its like begging to be robbed.

Comment: You completly right, however I don't see any problem if your docker won't be sent to production. Juts put the config file in gitnore and you will be fine.

Comment: This should be added as a warning in the answer then, otherwise, newcomers will think this is a perfectly fine way to do this.

Comment: @Munib Agreed and done.

Answer (score 6):

if you add this to your db container in your docker-compose.yml it should resolve the issue

```
environment:
  - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
```

Comment: It will also make your database unsecure.

Comment: This is like begging to be robbed. Don't do this, not even in dev env.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible scenario,

Check if ports have been used or not by other docker container.
Use command:

```
$ docker container ls --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}\t{{.Ports}}" -a
```

Then change your ports/expose in docker-compose file

Answer (score 0):

Updating the docker compose version to 3.8 helped me

Answer (score -1):

I thought I'd give an updated answer as I recently found a similar issue.

I had a similar setup where the app would connect correctly from docker running locally, but would fail when running in Jenkins.

Changing `image: postgres:latest` to `image: postgres:13.4-alpine` solved the issue.