# Failing to connect to a Postgres Container with psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, docker-compose, psycopg2

I have a docker-compose file that looks like this

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    stdin_open: true  
    tty: true 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_SAVE_DIRC}:${CONTAINER_SAVE_DIRC}
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  postgres:
    image: 'postgres'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "5432"
```

where variables like `POSTGRES_USER` are entries from a env file. app.Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM python:3.8.3-slim-buster
COPY src /src/
COPY init.sql .
COPY .env .
COPY run.sh run.sh
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN ls -a
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

The containers are created, then the user is logged into the `app` container w/ the main function of the program being called - this is when the database calls

From the `app` container I am attempting to connect to the `postgres` container via `psycopg2`. However when I attempt to do so, I receive the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No route to host
    Is the server running on host "postgres" (172.22.0.2) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

using a `psycopg2` call that looks like

```
with psy.connect(host='postgres', port=5432, user='postgres', password='postgres') as conn:
    ...
```

the entries of this psycopg2 call match the env file given to the `docker-compose` file.

My understanding is that Postgres uses port 5432 by default. Also that when `docker-compose` creates the two containers - it creates a docker network for those containers name `DIR_default` where `DIR` is the name of the directory the docker-compose file lives in, where each container can be accessed with using the name listed in the docker-compose file ('postgres' and 'app' in these cases).

Among various tries:

- I've checked and the database isn't going down between the container being created and the user being exec'd in.
- I've tried various little changes like changing the container names, postgres login info, etc.
- I've tried linking the postgres container name explicitly with `link: "postgres:postgres"`.
- Other solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750715/could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-using-postgres-docker-compose-and)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I see no reason why something as simple as this should be occurring, but also here I am.

---

**Edit:**

Pinging the `Postgres` container from the `app` container appears to be working when running `docker exec app ping postgres_container_name`. Is this a sign that the Docker network is set up correctly and the issue is something of mine?

---

**Edit 2:**

Tried clearing all images and containers, then restarting the Docker daemon and afterwards my PC. No change in either case.

For reference, the ping command looked like

```
docker exec python-app ping name_given_to_postgres_container
```

returning various statements which looked like

```
64 bytes from name_given_to_postgres_container.project_name_default (172.18.0.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.090 ms
```

which unless I am mistaken, I believe is signalling a succesful ping.

---

The top level .env file provided to docker-compose

```
HOST_SAVE_DIRC=~/python_projects/project_directory/directory_in_project
CONTAINER_SAVE_DIRC=/pdfs

POSTGRES_DB=project_name  # same as project_directory
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
```

---

Here is the `requirements.txt` file for the Python app as well

```
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.9
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
read-env==1.1.0
requests==2.23.0
urllib3==1.25.9
```

---

Exec-ing into the Postgres container with `docker exec -it container_id bash` and running `psql -U postgres` appears to be successful - even with `restart: always` removed. I can also see the database named in the docker-compose file is also created. I feel confident in saying this container isn't dying spontaneously.

However, hitting the 5432 port on the Postgres container with netcat via `nc name_given_to_postgres_container 5432-5433` returns an error similar to the one returned by psycopg2

```
arxivist_postgres_1 [172.22.0.3] 5433 (?) : No route to host
arxivist_postgres_1 [172.22.0.3] 5432 (postgresql) : No route to host
```

The same error is also returned with `curl`. So my guess the issue isn't with the Postgres container directly, psycopg2, or the host-name - but something with the port?

---

**Edit 3:**

As a last attempt to fix this project, the full project this post is referring to is posted [at this link](https://github.com/njhofmann/arXivist/tree/cmd-enum-overhaul). If anyone would like to download the repo and try building the docker containers themselves via `./start.sh` - that might be just what is needed to find a solution!

Comment: Please share the env file provided to docker-compose. If ping is successful then probably the issue lies in `psycopg2`.

Comment: Can you connect to the container that is running postgres (`sudo docker exec -it container-id bash`) and check if you can connect to the database from inside? It could be that the postgres settings don't allow outside connections

Comment: It's worth noting that DNS resolution works – the Python container knows what the `postgres` host name is, which suggests the Docker wiring is correct.  When you run this, is the PostgreSQL container fully started up?  If you're repeatedly running `docker-compose down; docker-compose up` everything will start from scratch and it's likely the database just isn't ready yet.

Comment: @leopal added the .env file. Believe the issue is simply in trying to connect to the 5432 port on the Postgres container?

Comment: @J.Auon Check David's comment. Ensure that the postgres container is ready when you try to connect through python.

Comment: @leopal I believe it is. The build process shows the Postgres container is ready to accept connections, and attempts to ping from the app container are successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I had Docker setup on my machine, which runs Fedora 32. However as I came to realize from [this article](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/), setting up Docker on Fedora 32 requires some extra steps I was not previously aware of.

Specifically for this issue, the command listed in the article to add Docker to whitelist Docker on the local network's firewall with the command

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=FedoraWorkstation --add-masquerade
```

So I believe the root cause of my issue was simply my `app` container being blocked from accessing the `postgres` container by the firewall. Making the above change made the program work finally!